# Why do I keep on losing permissions on my secondary hard drive?

Tags: 14.04, steam

My large secondary HDD that I use for storing all my steam games has once again up and decided that it needs to be it's own person again and I no longer have execute permissions for it. so all my steam games look as though they were uninstalled in one reboot. I'm sure I can figure out how to get those permissions back with a quick google search.

but, why? why did it happen at all and why does it keep on happening? first it took away my read/write permissions, then it took away my execute permissions. is there something in the ubuntu updates that I don't know about and I should be running a command after every update?

Comment: this is not an external hard drive.

Comment: You would profit from spending fewer words moaning and more providing details. Try attaching the [partition details](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/display-show-linux-partitions/), for instance, it might save your question from closure.

Comment: I've already stated that this is an issue with kernel -59 and not a problem with my drive.

Comment: If you are so sure it is a kernel issue, uninstall that kernel and use some other, right?.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the linked question, as OP states that this is related to a particular series of kernel releases. (I voted for "off-topic", but AU just bundles all votes to the category with the most votes.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the most recent kernel -59 breaks several apps including steam and wine. or rather there are some incompatabilites. there's a thread on github confirming it. I reverted to -58 and my steam games are all back and play just fine. however youtube videos are all black now.

here is the [launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1478989)

Comment: Don't forget to accept your own answer to mark your issue as solved, please.

Comment: I..uh, actually don't know how to

Comment: Click the grey tick below the vote count on the left of this answer. Also please take two minutes to read through the [tour] to get a little overview on how this site works. Thank you!